Side-Side-Side Theorem Proof Question

I understand the proof however I wanted to ask about the line segment pointed out in the picture, $\overline{\text{BE}}$. How do we know we can put that line through those points? I see how constructing the triangle in this manner such that the longest side of the triangle are the same and then from there we can use the propositions below however, what lets me say is that there is a line that goes through those points in that way. Would I have to say there is a point on $\overline{\text{AC}}$ such that it also intersects $\overline{\text{BE}}$? If I can say that then how could I prove it?
Thank you for your time and help!

It's usually axiomatic that we can join two points with a line segment. And, side note, this proof doesn't depend on using the longest side, any pair of congruent sides can be sandwiched together and the proof will work.

@RobinSparrow Thank you! How would I justify that A=D and C=F?

You should show the axioms you are using. One usually has an axiom about the partition of the plane by a line, ensuring that line $BE$ cuts line $AC$ if $B$ and $E$ are on opposite sides of line $AC$. Morover there should be a "transport" axiom enabling to construct an angle congruent to a given angle on a given side of a given ray, and so on.

It's good that you're looking at the situation so carefully. Normally we start Euclidean geometry with several axioms, classically these five: 1) we can draw a circle of given radius, 2) we can join two points with a line segment, 3) we can extend a given line segment past its endpoints, 4) all right angles are equal, and 5) parallel lines do not touch and are everywhere equidistant.
Suppose we are given a kite like in the first column, with pairs of congruent sides. Axiomatically, we can draw the line forming two isosceles triangles and mark congruent angles with $\alpha, \beta$. Now forget that line, erase it if you like. Mark $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$. Join the other vertices (axiomatic!). Now we have SAS operating for the remainder of the second column.

The hard thing about this setup - and having no idea where you are in the stream of logic being built - is that I have no idea how your triangles got apposed in the first place (third column). You're exactly right in your comment to be asking how to justify placing the triple-hash segment on the other triple-hash to begin with (i.e., to form the kite).
By way of comparison, I'll outline the classic start leading to the SSS theorem, by Euclid:

1.1: build an equilateral on a line segment
1.2: move a line segment of some length to a given point (needs equilateral for construct).
1.3: cut a line segment of some length from a given line at a point (application of 1.2).
1.4: SAS - superposition enabled by the proven ability to move lines
1.5: isosceles: equal sides imply equal base angles
1.6: isosceles: equal base angles imply equal sides
1.7: with 3 given line segments, one and only one triangle may be constructed on one side of the line (needs isosceles for proof by contradiction).
1.8: SSS: because one and only one such triangle is constructible if we move one on top of the other (superposition).

So to place $A$ on $D$, and $C$ on $F$, in your diagram, you do need some kind of proper way to move line segments of a specified length around the plane. Note that once you have SSS, provided you prove you can construct the triangle, you have a proven way to copy/move angles around the plane as you wish.

Thank you!!!!! You're awesome.

I was trying some things out to see if I could construct this shape. Given we have two triangles ABC and DEF, let the angle DEF be alpha. So By congruence axiom 4, there is a unique ray BC' congruent to FE (by CA1) on a given side such that angle alpha and alpha' are congruent. Then we have a segment AC' congruent to DF (by CA1) and by SAS triangle ABC' is congruent to triangle DFE so by transitivity triangle ABC is congruent to triangle DEF. Would this work?

@myapepe you gotta check that with your teacher, your naming scheme of theorems is from your book, not a universal scheme. Good luck!
